# Managing parameters upon inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

Currently I have in my `Java` program two classes, which share majority of the methods and both initialize pretty large `HashMap`. Therefore, it would be beneficial to inherit one of them from another or both of them from a single parent class. However, the problem is that one of the classes always fills the `HashMap` with specific set of values, and thus has only a parameterless constructor, while the other fills it based on user input, and thus must have only a constructor with a `String` parameter (which is getting then parsed to derive values that go into the `HashMap`; an empty `String` makes no sense and throws an `Exception`).

Taken together, I came up with three possible solutions:

1. Keep two fully independent but highly redundant classes.
2. Make a common parent class with a parameterless constructor, which will lead to undesired behavior unless called from one specific child.
3. Make a common parent class with only parameter constructor. The first class then packs its default parameters into `String`, which is getting then parsed to derive the parameters again. This would affect performance drastically.

Is there a better solution, which does not have drawbacks of the listed ones?

**EDIT:**

It is a bit hard to explain specific details, but in general I want to simulate a biochemical reaction and I need objects for reagents (which are in fact mixtures in buffers) and buffers (which have standardized concentrations of chemicals in them). It would make no sense to have an 'empty' reagent or a standard buffer as reagent. In both cases, however, the `HashMap` holds the concentrations of the components.

Comment: What will you be saving by combining two large `Map`(s) into one `Map` containing the values from the two *smaller* `Map`(s)? That's like saving money by spending 2 dimes instead of 4 nickels.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch  The `Map` and the majority of operations on it are the same; however, it must be filled with different values in different child classes, where the right values for one child are absurd for the other and vice versa.

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, inheritance should be used wheb one class1 IS-A class2 (Dog IS-A Animal, Integer IS-A Number, etc...) and not just to allow code-reuse. Are your two classes related like that?

Comment: @mattfreake If the two classes share the majority of the methods, then it's almost certain that they also share the same basic purpose.  So it's almost certain that there's some common concept that can be used as a common parent, that both classes can say they are "IS-A".

Comment: How about "Make a common _abstract_ parent class with a parameterless constructor that does nothing"?  I.e. the default constructor.  If the two constructors don't have that much in common, then let each child class have its own constructor.  Your comment in #2 about "undesired behavior" wouldn't apply, because the constructor wouldn't do anything.

Comment: @ajb I'm sure you're right in this case, but I can think of examples where two classes, not following the single-responsibilty-principle could share of majority of methods, but not have an IS-A relationship, and inheritance would be inappropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like option 3 might be the best of the three you identified.  A variant would be to have the superclass constructor take a HashMap parameter that the subclasses are responsible for filling.  (That avoids the efficiency issue you are worried about.)

For example

```
public abstract class C1 {
   private Map<String, String> params;
   public C1(Map<String, String> params) { this.params = params; }
}

public class C2 extends C1 {
   public C2(String a, String b) {
      super (new HashMap<String, String>() {{
                 put("a", a);
                 put("b", b);
             }});
   }
}

public class C3 extends C1 {
   private HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();

   public C3() {
      super (myMap);
      // now put values into myMap based on user input.
   }
}
```

However, as they say, "the devil is in the details"<sup>1</sup>.  We can't sensibly discuss the pro's and con's of these approaches in the context of your problem without knowing the details of your problem.

This illustrates that reuse-by-inheritance works best if the original classes were designed with inheritance in mind.  At least your context allows you to consider a significant refactoring.  In a lot of contexts, you are constrained by the extent of dependencies on the existing structure.  (Especially dependencies in "customer" code.)

---

Your concern about it "not making sense" to be passing empty maps is addressed by making the superclass abstract.  It would be up to the subclass to provide "sensical"<sup>2</sup> constructor parameters, depending on how the subclass constructors are intended to be used.

---

<sup>1 - For instance, the kind of issues that Elliott is talking about ...</sup>

<sup>2 - Sensical (adjective) - the opposite of nonsensical.</sup>